# jQuery alert on unload except when save button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

I have a textbox and I want it to show an alert when leaving the page with unsaved changes, except if you click the submit button.
This works great, except it still alerts you if the submit button is pressed and I really have no idea how to fix it.

I have 2 files, my Set.js to take the actions of the BBcode, and my script.js

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var saveClicked = false;

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        if(y != $("#markItUp").val()) {
            if(!saveClicked) {          
                return 'You have unsaved changes!';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Set.js

```
{
    name: 'Save',
    className:"miu-save",
    call: function() {
        $('form#edit').submit(); 
        saveClicked = true;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
{
    name: 'Save',
    className:"miu-save",
    call: function() {
        $('form#edit').submit(); 
        saveClicked = true;
    }
},
```

to

```
{
    name: 'Save',
    className:"miu-save",
    call: function() {
        saveClicked = true; // true is called first here if you notice and then submit
        $('form#edit').submit(); 
    }
},
```

and also this is necessary

```
var saveClicked = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to declare you saveClicked var outside the document.ready function

Answer (score 1):

Put your `saveClicked` out side of `document.ready`. That way it will be global and then only one can set its value to `true` or `false`.

So your script should be like:

```
  var saveClicked = false;
  $(document).ready(function(){

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
   if(y != $("#markItUp").val()){
     if(!saveClicked){           
   return 'You have unsaved changes!';
  }}
 });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the online link where this can be checked?

Comment: Sure but it is in danish
http://japseyz.dk/Test/Login

Login with StackOverflow and Test123

To get to the BBcode editor press the "Ændre side" in the top right corner

Comment: oops.. asking to login.. if u are comfortable, then u can send the credentials on gauravpandey.uit@gmail.com

Comment: The credentials is above... Username StackOverflow and Test123

I'll just remove the user once this is fixed :)

Comment: Yeah... got your problem.. see the solution provided by @Mayur below... hopefully it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will work, but maybe if you start by doing

```
saveClicked = true;
```

and **only then** do

```
$('form#edit').submit();
```

that would do the trick.

Comment: I am not sure i get what you mean